# Table is too big for iopart format

Tags: tables, longtable, fontsize, journal-publishing

I am trying to make a large table in a document with the `iopart` class. The table is too long and wide to fit on a single page. I'd like some way to decrease the width, perhaps by decreasing the font size and reducing the horizontal spacing between columns. Here's the code that makes the table

```
\begin{longtable}{@{}llllll}
\caption{\label{tab:table} Caption }\\
\footnotesize
\centering
\br
&&&& Header 5-1 & Header 6-1 \\
\ns
& Header 2-2 && Header 4-2 & Header 5-2 & Header 6-2 \\
\ns
Header 1-3 & Header 2-3 & Header 3-3 &  Header 4-3 & Header 5-3 & Header 6-3 \\
\mr
a & b & c & d & e & f \\
\br
\end{longtable}
```

Data in cells a and d are somewhat long, but can't be split over lines. Data in the others cells is a little shorter. Does anyone have any tricks for making `longtable`s shorter in the `iopart` class?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/47927 ?